# Joining SOLR Collections on ColdFusion Server

Tags: solr, coldfusion

I'm running ColdFusion 10. I need to somehow perform a JOIN on two collections on the same server. I've read up on shards a little but I am not quite sure how to implement it.

I have two collections, "products" and "units". The products collection has about 4,000 records and contains the product description, and other large text fields. The units collection contains all the size and color combinations for each product (up to 500+ per product, over 1 million total), which I need to be able to search on. I have a custom field in each, productid_i that I can use to join the two.

I had to do it like this because it brought the server to it's knees when I tried to index a million plus records with the long description fields in each.

How can I join these two collections so I can search on products.description, units.size and units.color?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you could say search for units on size and colors, this would give you all products matching these units. Create a list of product ids from that and search the corresponding products filtering on description.

Comment: Thanks Marc. My problem with that approach is that if someone searches for +"Balcony Bra" +Black, the Balcony Bra string would return results from the Products collection and the Black string would return results from the Units collection, but together would not return any results from either collection. So I would have to create an Advanced Search with separate form fields for color/size and everything else.